# database not showing on phpmyadmin, still working on website

Tags: phpmyadmin

**Explanation**

So around 3 months ago I created a php website and created a database that links to that site on phpmyadmin.

All was working fine, database tables were echoing well and the connection to the DB was working. After not using the site for a few months, just recently i tried to load up XAMPP and the mySQL connection could not be established. I searched online for help and found people suggested deleting a certain file in the setup folder (cant remember which one, sorry). 
This didn't solve the problem. but later I found a fix and all was good.

However...

**Problem**

When using the website, like before, all the data is fine, the connection is working and search functions/log in/sessions are all working great.

But when I go onto phpmyadmin...the database i created is no longer there, and i cant find it anywhere!?

Obviously, i thought the file i deleted must be the source of the issue, however, it couldn't have deleted the DB itself, as everything (website side) is working fine!

Does anybody have any advice as to where this db can be found, or what could have happened?

I'm not too familiar with phpmyadmin but now just about enough to get by, but cannot see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials (user, password, hostname) used to connect to MySQL in your website are probably different than those you are entering in phpMyAdmin. Another possibility is that your database has been hidden in phpMyAdmin (for example with the 'only_db' directive).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, username/password/hostname are all correct, i'm as sure as can be. 

however, not heard of the database being hidden? is there a way to "unhide" this?

Comment: The 'only_db' directive in phpMyAdmin's configuration file is the one to use to hide a database.